# django template: Is extended template able to change css in parent page?

Tags: django, templates, extend

I have two django template pages, one of them is "base.html", with basic html tags setup as a base template. Now I have a page "child.html" that extends it, with something like `{% extends "base.html" %}` in it. Now I have to change `<body>` background color for this particular page, so in the css of "child.html" I wrote:

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    /* some other css here */
}
```

But the body doesn't seem to respond to any changes. I think I must have missed something. Please help, thanks.

**Edit:** 
In "child.html", I simply have

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site-media/css/template_conf.css"/>
```

and I try to change body css in `template_conf.css`, and there's no other page that includes `template_conf.css`.

Comment: What do you mean 'in the css of "child.html"'? How is that CSS being included in the template?

Comment: And is that `link` tag contained in a template block that is defined by the parent, so it is actually rendered? Does it appear in the rendered HTML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the main template:

```
<body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}">
...
</body>
```

Then in the child template, just define the block:

```
{% block body_class %} my_new_body_css_class {% endblock %}
```

This will render a `<body class="my_new_body_css_class">...</body>` and you have to define this class in a linked CSS.

Answer (score 11):

To do this add a block in base.html in the head that allow you to inset another css AFTER the one in base.html

```
<head>

    .... other head tags ....

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site-media/css/template_conf.css"/>
    {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
</head>
```

This allows you to override css tags in `template_conf.css` by adding in another `<link>` tag in child.html

```
{% block extra_css %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site-media/css/child_template.css"/>
{% endblock %}
```

This allows you to override the partd of base.html that needs to change, while still being able to tweak the parts of the page in child.html that are required.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder which one is the ideal approach. This one or the one suggested by @ablm. Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 1):

if you see the new css loaded in the firebug or other browser debugger,
please try:

```
body {
background-color: #000000 !important;
/* some other css here */
```

}