# How to change the background picture and content of each pages in django way

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have a base.html file and 10+ other pages with different background picture and contents. I tried using `{% extends "base.html" %}` , but how can I change my background picture and content in each pages if am doing so? Please help me on this case. Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

My directory:

[image]

And my base.html:

```
     {% load staticfiles %}

      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
        <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
          <meta name="description" content="">
          <meta name="author" content="">
          <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

          <title>Parasol.</title>

          <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
            <link href="{%  static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{%  static 'css/navbar-static-top.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="{%  static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

          <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
          <link href="navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
          <style>
          {% block additional_styles %}
     body {
      background:url(static/custom/img/voice.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
     }
  </style>

      {% endblock %}

        </head>
        <body>
       <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url "home" %}">Parasol.</a>
              </div>
              <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Photos <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <li><a href="{% url "firstsite" %}">Timeline</a></li>
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">Quotes<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                  <li><a href="{% url "friends" %}">Friends</a></li>
                </ul>
              </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
            </div>
          </nav>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron">
              <h1>Just her and the revolution</h1>
              <p>
      <a href="{% url 'go' %}" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Let's take a trip.. </a>
              </p>
            </div>

          </div>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
          <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>

        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: Please explain what is the content you are talking about? Is that dynamical data or static one?

Comment: Its not dynamic. its static one

Comment: Seems like I just need to override my body css in my base in my all other pages. How to do that

Comment: My CSS for body:
`body{
    background:url(../img/voice.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many different ways to do that, which are dependent on the type of the content, your project and the templates structure. Regarding background picture, you can simply add block to your *base.html*:

```
{% block additional_styles %}
<style>
   body {
    background-image: url(images/base.jpg);
   }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

and then in your *template_1.html* (which is the template for some other pages):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block additional_styles %}
<style>
   body {
    background-image: url(images/1.jpg);
   }
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Sorry am very new to django. What is additional styles means?

Comment: @blackwindow that's just a random name for the block. In general, in your browser the contents of this block in base.html (parent template) will be overwrited with the contents of block with same name in template_1.html (child template, which is inheriting base html with {% extends 'base.html' %} For additional reading: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/ The template system is the core thing of Django, so that article is definitely worth reading.

Comment: Hi svfat, I tried the method as above (editted my question). But no idea why my background image is loading. Can you please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: @blackwindow i don't clearly undersand your problem. You background image is loading or isn't?

Comment: @blackwindow and you should move <style> tag INTO {% block ... %} and change url to url({%  static 'custom/img/voice.jpg' %})

Comment: Ok Thats great! Thanks:)

Comment: I am trying to move the above styling to a css file but guess that isn't really feasible? My body tag is in the base.html. Barring a few, almost all my pages have the same background, so it would be good to just create a class for it and not write the above styling code in all the pages that have that background. Thoughts?

Comment: Update: I used <body class="{% block body_class %}{% endblock %}"> to achieve what I described above. This post helped: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14781481/1526703

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer add below tags in base.html

```
{% block additional_styles %}
{% endblock %}
```

in your `<head>` tag.
Like (in base.html)

```
    <head>
        {% block additional_styles %}
        {% endblock %}
    </head>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may do that by overriding bootstrap's predefined styles either as in css file or extra styles section or superseding a specific sections styles, e.g.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-color: #32CD32;">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top" style="background-image: url({% static "img/ok.jpg" %}); background-repeat: repeat-x;">
```